# how to make many def's work one after another if one of them use WGET?

Tags: python, function, wget

I wrote a parser that works well, but I had a problem with the amount of memory that I am ready to allocate for storing downloaded files, so I decided to parse all URLs in parts, (download via vget, parse data and add it to a notebook, delete downloaded data and so on in a circle)
the question is how to create a function that will wait for wget to download all files and then start parsing? because in jupyter the function is displayed as completed and everything is transferred to cmd, it turns out that the next function on the list is the parser that simply parses up to 10 samples, because wget did not finish its work

```
#creating new folder in project for urls.txt x 20
def cr_fol_data_txt():
    os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\T\\data\\data_txt')
#creating urls files
def cr_urls_txt():
    for i in range(20):
        with open(f'C:/Users/T/data/data_txt/urls{i}.txt', 'w') as out:
            for item in result[100 * i:100 * (i+1)-1]:
                out.write(item[0] + '\n')

#creating new folder in project for html files
def cr_fold_data_html():
    os.mkdir('C:\\Users\\T\\data\\data_html')

def download_html():
    for i in range(20):
        os.system(f'START /B /HIGH wget --compression=gzip -P C:/Users/T/data/data_html -i C:/Users/T/data/data_txt/urls{i}.txt')


cr_fol_data_txt()
cr_urls_txt()
cr_fold_data_html()
download_html()
parse()
```

I want the parse function to wait for all files to download, is that possible? without manually entering the approximate download time, namely the complete end?

Comment: Why are you using `wget` when Python has a built-in `requests` library for fetching web pages?

Comment: i was looking for a fast way to download 100,000 pages and it was possible using wget because there you can run 20 processes in parallel and it really gives a boost, unlike the parallel function in joblib, i don't know maybe with requests you can achieve the same result , but I repeat, I did not find such an answer anywhere, is it really so?